# Mobile Safari - are there limits in place to prevent large data consumption on first page load?

Tags: javascript, ios, html, mobile-safari

I have a webapp, that when loaded for the first time has a long initialization sequence.  Basically it calls an external API to get loads of data which it caches upon completion, using HTML5 localstorage API.

The issue is, it never gets through initialization in Mobile Safari on the first attempt.  At around the same point each time, my AJAX calls just stop firing.  When I refresh the page, it starts initialization over again, but this time gets through.

If I clear the browser cache and start this process over again, it is always the same.  Fail on first attempt, succeed on subsequent refreshes.

I'm aware that there are certain barriers in place in Mobile Safari to prevent large consumption of data unless in direct response to user input (such as the HTML5 audio tag not being able to 'autoplay').

I'm wondering if there is something similar in place for loading web pages for the first time that immediately consume large amounts of data.  And by refreshing, Mobile Safari takes that as your explicit permission to do so.

Anyone know?

Comment: Safari doesn't allow the autoplay of `<audio>` to prevent pages alarming the user by playing sounds without warning. I don't think it's anything to do with slowing data consumption.

Comment: Wrong.  "In Safari on iOS (for all devices, including iPad), where the user may be on a cellular network and be charged per data unit, preload and autoplay are disabled."  http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009523-CH5-SW1

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you start with a simple, quick-loading base html file, which will give your user something to look at right away -- even if it's just a simple "Loading...".

Then use ajax to get your "loads of data," using `window.onload` for example. Ideally give your user something to read or interact with so they don't notice the wait, or a progress indicator, to know the site is actually working.

People are impatient, and when faced with a blank screen and the browser loading indicator not making progress, they're going to assume your site is broken within a few seconds.

The *certain barriers...to prevent large consumption of data* are probably there for exactly this reason, to improve user experience and prevent monstrous web pages.

Comment: This is a port of an app meant to run in an in-dash vehicle display unit.  Being ported to browser simply to demo product on an iPad.  It actually does have a loading indicator as well as progress messages at the bottom of the screen to note which items are loading.  If this is an intentional blocker from Apple, I wish it would go away if user is connected via WiFi.  In total, I am loading in and caching only about 800KB.

Comment: In that case, you should only load your indicator and progress messages in the base html document -- so the DOM loads and the screen is painted with that, then go fetch the rest of the data with AJAX.

Comment: The load indicator/messages aren't the issue.  They show up just fine and my app is already set up this way.  Its just that after so many AJAX calls, the browser seems to just stop executing my javascript code for no reason.  Works fine on every other desktop browser, and will work after a refresh.  But on first load after clearing the browser cache, my code just stops running.

Comment: google "mobile safari ajax response size limit" -- there are many anecdotal examples that there is a limit, maybe 512KB. So you need to chunk your data load into multiple ajax calls. Your calling it "initialization" suggests the initial html page load, not ajax calls.